Interrupt Handling
I want to create a priority based interrupt handler for real time events in windows . Its my OS project. What software am I supposed to use? Help me start with my project.
I want to know the software to use for my project and the code guidance.

Study carefully the target hardware and Windows driver architecture.  You may have to purchase libraries etc. from MS.
